# Mount Script cannot be created in Bolt A58

Tags: rooting

I have a bolt a58. I want increase internal memory by parttion. I followed exactly the same steps what you've in the turorial "How To Increase Internal Memory on any Micromax". After selecting FAT32/FAT16 format in Link2SD it gives error: "Mount Script Error. Mount script cannot be created. mount:No such file or directory". Its an 8GB card. I'll explain all I did before this--

1. Took backup of SD card and deleted all files (did not format)
2. I used "MiniTool Partion Wizard" to patition memory, the card being in a card reader
3. I reserved 1GB of Memory in FAT32(as primary)
4. Then copied back all files
5. Opened Link2SD and selected FAT32/FAT16....
   and this gave the above error....

Please help me....

Thank you all...